# Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise

Tags: angular, npm, angular7

I work with Angular 7.1.4. I want to generate a new module with the following line;

`ng g m order-process`

But I encountered an error:

```
Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise.
```

How to fix this?
Node: 8.11.3

---

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnaqV.png) ( https://prnt.sc/o3cg54 )

Comment: instead of `m` try with `module` like this `ng g module order-process`.

Comment: I was try but doesn't solved

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'd solved my problem. My angular/cli version is 7.0.7 but I was find the @schematics/angular@8.0.3 in package-lock.json. So, I run the "npm install @schematics/angular@7.0.7 --save-dev" command and solved my problem.
Thank you for interested.

Comment: > npm install @schematics/angular@latest -g
> delete package-lock and node_modules
> npm i
solved my issue. THANK YOU

Answer (score 13):

Run `npm install @schematics/angular@7.0.7 --save-dev`
replace version with the same as your `@angular/cli` (in this scenario, **7.0.7**)

Answer (score 5):

My problem was that my node version was on `8.x.x` but angular >= `8.x.x` requires a node version >= `10.x.x`

Im using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md) to change node version. 
Install it with like so (check link for windows usage)

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.2/install.sh | bash
```

after installation install node version 10.x.x

```
nvm install 10
```

then switch in terminal like this

```
nvm use 10
```

Comment: Hm, yes we encounter like this case in some cases welded from node version. But my problem located inside the package-lock.json. My Angular CLI version is 7.x.x but @schematics/angular version is 8.x.x inside of package-lock.json. Thats the problem. I changed the @schematics/angular version 8.x.x to 7.x.x(same version with Angular CLI) and its solved. I specify the @schematics/angular 7.x.x version in package.json.

Answer (score 3):

Had this issue while using Using: 
@angular/cli 8.1.1, 
@angular-devkit/schematics 8.0.1,
Node v8.9.4,
Upgrading to Node 10 fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting existing `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` directory helped me running the `ng new` command without error

Comment: This helped to solve the issue for me. The most simple and least invasive solution so far!

Answer (score 1):

Angular CLI: 8.0.3
Node: 10.16.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.2.7

I also encountered this problem, but it was resolved when I chose to reinstall node！I hope I can help you！

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your attention, I did re-install for the nodejs but it's not working for me :( Ng --version => angular: 7.0.7 node: 10.16.0

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with the angular schematics-
use npm install --save @angular/pwa@0.6.8

Also you can try lowering the pwa version if you face further issues.

The issue thread on github-
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11663

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not related to the initial question, but since this is the first hit in google for the error message, I'll leave some information here for everybody seeing this error when **upgrading Apollo (`apollo-angular`) from 1.x to 2.x with `ng update apollo-angular`**.

Check if you have installed `@angular-devkit/schematics` and if it is the same version as your `@angular/cli` package.
If not install with `@angular-devkit/schematics@<your.@angular/cli.version>`. Then commit the changes, make sure you don't commit the changed Apollo version from the failed run and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate a blank new project and check if you get the same error there too when creating a module using the CLI.

If you do, then I'd recommend to re-install angular.

Comment: Thanks I was generate a new project and then successfully generate a module. There was no problem in new project

Comment: you could check the used package versions in the new test project and your "real" project, maybe the real one uses some outdated/buggy versions of some packages.

Comment: Hm, its brilliant, thank you. I was try to compare two project. I did copy package.json content from "real" project and then paste to content of package.json in the new test project. So, again I did successfully generate a module in the test project, there was no problem.. However, I'm having still error in "real" project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the CLI version 6.0.8 and then install in a clean project try ng add @angular/pwa@0.6.8

Seems like the error hasn't been solved by the core team so in the meanwhile we have to use a lower version

Comment: Are you sure? This solution is so eerie. Another libraries will be affected at the end of this solition.

Answer (score 0):

It is an error in node.
It works with carrying out 3 steps
1.- Uninstall and reinstall the (last) version of the node
2.- Inside the project, delete the package-lock.json file (it will be automatically regenerated) and the node_modules folder
3.- run npm install to reload the node_modules

Comment: Thanks, I'd try but problem is not solved with this solution. Also, The problem is solved as you see in the answers. My Angular CLI version is 7.x.x but @schematics/angular version is 8.x.x in content of package-lock that's the problem. So, I'd install the schematic version 7.x.x(same the Angular/CLI)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your angular cli version and @schematics/angular should be same 
then only
 ng add @angular/pwa < project name same as in angular.json file >

will execute and run successfully and the service worker module will be added to the project