# "Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise" is how to find solve the issue, iam creating on new app in angular "ng new sample-angular"

Tags: angular

I am creating angular new Single Page Application, but an issue arisen when

```
ng new angular-sample
```

how to fix the issues on angular7, I have given my best. But not fixed.

My module versions are

**Node 10.15.3**

**npm 6.4.1**

**Angular cli 7.2.4**

At the beginning,

*Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes*

*Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS*

```
Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647865/invalid-rule-result-instance-of-class-promise this might help you

Answer (score 4):

Run `npm install @schematics/angular@7.2.4 --save-dev`
replace version with the same as your `@angular/cli` (in this scenario, **7.2.4**)

Delete package-lock and node_modules. Then run npm install again.