# Error while creating components with Nativescript cli

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular, tns

I'm building a brand new app in NativeScript, but I'm having issues to use the nativescript cli to create component/services/etc.. I'm just keep getting:

```
Error: Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise.
    at t.project (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:250:1038)
...
```

I review this kind of error and the fixes for all was to have the same version of @angular/cli and @schematics/angular and then remove package-lock.json and node_modules, but none of this works.
Below you have the package.json

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.domain.app",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.0.2"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.0.2"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "~8.2.0",
    "nativescript-angular-cli": "^0.1.9",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.6",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "~7.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "^0.7.2",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~8.2.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "^8.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "gitHead": "42f2a6a9c94eaf9c68d2a41e0daaa1a2544bc28f",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

Is there anything else I can do? Do you guys see anything weird? It's just a brand new app. And I already built two or three apps with Nativescipt (older version) without issues like this.

Comment: [invalid-rule-result-instance-of-class-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647865/invalid-rule-result-instance-of-class-promise)

Comment: Yes, I saw that. For that reason I clarify that having the same version of @angular/cli and schematics/angular didn't fix the issue

Comment: having the same issue here

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with simply using the ng command i know you said this is for nativescript but for me the ng command generates the Nativescript dns files as well if its shared or the correct ones if its native only so simply try

```
ng generate c name
```